# matching the values from an array containing values

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an array containing the following values

```
final String[] headers = { "abc", "def", "rty", "yui"  };
```

now i am iterating over the excel sheet cells by using apache poi  as shown below

```
 for (Row row : firstSheet) {

            for (Cell cell : row) {
              if ("abc".equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
```

now as shown below the value "abc" is hardcoded that is i want to customize it in such a way that when cell value is read then it should be matched from witih in the array i want to remove this hard coding so in other words the cell value is read which will always be a string  and then that same value is searched with in the array itself please advise how to customise this

Comment: you have to iterate over the array in another loop. Otherwise just put your words hashset and have o(1) search time complexity.

Comment: @EduardoDennis Thanks a lot , request you to please show in detail so that i can grasp in details please thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend to use a `Set` instead of an `Array`. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<String> headers = new HashSet<String>();
        headers.add("abc");
        headers.add("def");
        headers.add("rty");
        headers.add("yui");

        for (Row row : firstSheet) {

            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if(headers.contains(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                    // matching 
                } else {
                    // not matching
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet to replace the hardcode values.

```
List<String> listHeader=Arrays.asList(header);
for (Row row : firstSheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        if(listHeader.contains(cell.getStringCellValue()) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create `List` instead of `Array` and then use `contains` method in if clause.

Comment: GalaThanks can you please post how it can be implemented that will help to grasp more

Comment: whoever has down voted this answer, please also tell the reason for that.